# how to use subset with strings in R?

Tags: r, string

I'm learning R and I am looking the way to remove all observations from my data frame that has `varA == "Unknown"` and `varB == ""`.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
subset(dataFrame, varA != "Unknown" & varB != ""))
```

However this is obviously not working...

Any idea on how to get my subset done?

Comment: You should provide some example. Try `subset(dataFrame, !(varA =='Unknown' & varB==''))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change the code slightly

```
 subset(dataFrame, !(varA =='Unknown' & varB==''))
```

#### data

```
    dataFrame <- data.frame(varA= c('Unknown', LETTERS[1:3], 'Unknown'), 
          varB=c(LETTERS[1:4], ''))
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg I intend to use `sample`, but somehow forgot it.  Good observation :-)

Answer (score 4):

Negating a conjunct (`&`ed) logical condition creates a disjunction (`|`ed), according to [De Morgan’s laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
subset(dataFrame, ! (varA == "Unknown" & varB == ""))
```

is the same as

```
subset(dataFrame, varA != "Unknown" | varB != "")
```